# Two conjectural congruences for Franel numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, congruences

Recall that the Franel numbers are given by
$$f_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^3\ \ \ (n=0,1,\ldots).$$

**Question.** How to prove my following conjecture?

**Conjecture**. For each odd prime $p$, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{f_{k-1}}{k8^{k-1}}\equiv-p^2B_{p-3}\pmod{p^3}\tag{1}$$
and
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{f_k}{k8^k}\equiv 3q_p(2)-\frac 32 p\,q_p(2)^2+p^2q_p(2)^3\pmod{p^3},\tag{2}$$
where $B_{p-3}$ is the $(p-3)$th Bernoulli number and $q_p(2)$ is the Fermat quotient $(2^{p-1}-1)/p$.

*Remark*. Let $p>3$ be a prime. In my 2013 paper [Congruences for Franel numbers](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aam.2013.06.004) [Adv. Appl. Math. 51 (2013), 524-535], I proved that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^k}kf_k\equiv0\pmod{p^2}\ \ \text{and}\ \ \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}f_k\equiv0\pmod{p}.$$
 By Remark 1.1 of this paper, both $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold modulo $p$.